# foreach or Repeater - which is better?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, loops

I'm building a website in ASP.Net, using MVC, and need to list a set of results. Both of the following work as I want them to but I'm wondering which is faster, cleaner and/or better - or if another option entirely would be more appropriate?

Note: `ViewData.Model` is of type `IEnumerable<Thing>` and I need to display more attributes than `Name` - I've cropped the code for this example.

---

```
<% foreach (var thing in ViewData.Model)
   { %>
   <p><%= thing.Name %></p>
<% }; %>
```

---

```
<% rptThings.DataSource = ViewData.Model;
   rptThings.DataBind(); %>
<asp:Repeater ID="rptThings" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <p><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %></p>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

---

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`foreach` is definitely faster, if you don't specifically screw up something. `Repeater` is cleaner of course, and more neatly separates UI and logic. Sometimes you need more conditions (other than different look even and odd rows) to render your stuff properly which makes `foreach` the only choice.

I personally prefer `Repeater` for normal situations and `foreach` for more complex ones.

EDIT: I was talking about plain ASP.NET with WebControls. For MVC and even pages that are mostly generated by code, I agree that foreach is more straightforward and cleaner.

Answer (score 13):

`foreach` is the way to go for ASP.NET MVC. Why? i personally avoid *any* legacy `asp:xxx` controls .. because they could possibly have the bloat that exists with the webforms model. Secondly, what about all the `event delegates` you have to wire up? you're starting to mix and match architectures, IMO, so this could seriously lead to real spagetti code with crazy maintenence and support issues. (IMO: DataBinder.Eval == very evil :( :( :(  )

The only `asp:xxx` control i use is the `mastpage / content control`(because there are no alternatives to it).

Lastly, doing `foreach` in asp.net mvc is NOT spagetti code, as many people believe. I know i did when i first saw the initial mvc demo's. If anything, it actually makes the UI so much more cleaner than before, imo .. so much more maintainable. IMO, spagetti code is when u have lots of `<% .. %>` doing business logic and ui logic and (gag) db access. Remember, that's what peeps did in the wild west of asp.net *classic* :P

### Summary

Stick with `foreach` and avoid using any webform controls - it's simple, very efficient and very possible to do.

Comment: ``The only asp:xxx control i use is the mastpage / content control(because there are no alternatives to it).`` - wait, what?! What's wrong with nesting shared layout pages? I am doing this in my project and it works just as expected!

Comment: @iamserious - what version of ASP.NET MVC are you using?

Comment: MVC 3! Actually, I've never used any other mvc frameworks so apologies if you couldn't do this in previous versions!

Comment: AH :) Check when I answered this post. was a while back, MVC1. Now, we have regions in `Razor` which means can finally ditch that `ASP:SMELL crap.` Oh and there's nothing wrong with nested shared layout pages .. never suggested there was. Just complained that (back then) the only asp:YUCK control we still had to use was masterpage / content controls .. cause `Razor` wasn't around.

Comment: Yes! I should have seen the date posted, my mistake, apologies! Looks like you dearly despise asp web forms!

Comment: Aye - thank <insert fav deity here> for Razor / MVC :) :) :) :) :) :)

Answer (score 2):

I use the extension method repeater from Phil Haack. Best of both worlds. http://haacked.com/archive/2008/05/03/code-based-repeater-for-asp.net-mvc.aspx

Comment: Wouldn't this be faster?

<% int i = 0;
   foreach (var thing in ViewData.Model)
   { %>
   <p class="row<%= i % 2 %>"><%= thing.Name %></p>
<% i++;
   }; %>

for classes .row0 & .row1

That could be silly - just throwing it out there.

Comment: @Emma: surely, you are the not [THE EMMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_Emma,_Forever_Ago) that Bon Iver [sings about](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UrMmr1oMPGA)?

Answer (score 1):

```
<p each="var item in ViewData.Model">${item.Name}</p>
```

Mmm, tasty [Spark](http://dev.dejardin.org/).

Comment: To add to Brad's answer, Spark is an alternate MVC template framework, similar to Razor but with different syntax. I'm a big fan of Spark, but fewer developers are familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [another option](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Grid&referringTitle=Documentation).  I have not used this myself, but looks interesting.